# Why isn't the prompt printing to the console/terminal while using prompt-sync in VS Code Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, prompt

I am working on a small project with VS Code using Node.js. I wanted to install a module to extend the program to receive user input. I found the npm prompt-sync as a hopeful browser-free alternative.

I have successfully installed the npm prompt-sync and attached the module to my project. I've verified both node and npm are installed. Simply calling the instructed code results in the program running to no end:

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({sigint: true});
let name = prompt("Please enter your name: ");
```

The prompt does not print anywhere in the terminal or debugging console. I'm guessing the program is waiting for input somewhere, but there is no indication.

Comment: How exactly are you running this? I would expect you'd open a terminal and run `node my-js-file.js` but if you're doing something different that might explain why you're not seeing the prompt

Comment: I'm just hitting 'Run and Debug'. I'm very new and naive to this, am I supposed to be doing anything differently?

Comment: You have actually answered my question and it's working. Thank you so much!